# Chooseing between SQLite and raw files

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an app that preload thousands of data (this data contains lyrics of songs and the author).  Initially I thought of using SQLite but because of the problem with extra copy of preloaded database in the asset folder (since this will increase the size of the app) forced me to think towards files; that is storing each lyrics in the raw folder and calling them through input stream on my activity.

I would like to know which of this technique is best. Should I use SQLite or  should I use files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SQL Database should serve you well.

Make sure to perform bulk updates as SQL database transactions.

The number of transactions per seconds is pretty low, but you can change thousands of rows in a single transaction.

I would also recommend starting out with FTS tables, which will provide good query performance and power.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently making MediaPlayer myself, and i use SQLite. I used File before and it was quite slow. I have 350 songs and i store a lot of info in database. (Everything except AlbumArt,that is loaded in run time).I store complete music info from IDV3tag. Its a bit harder to make it work right but its much faster. If you have any problems contact me for help.
EIDT: If you have large number of files use Index, but be careful to delete it on database rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

May be the [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) will be the good option for you:

1. They are stored on the external shared memory
2. You can post them to google play without compression
3. This enables to not to store two copies of the DB on the device

Answer (score 0):

First of all accessing indexed data is most of the time faster in android using SQLite DB than using row files. so if it were me I would go with DB option.

But there are many tricks you can use to optimize the UX for example you can copy the data on stages like :

- Think of the data that should be available immediately at lunch and copy it first. (maybe song names table ).
- Copy the rest of the data in a background thread without the user even noticing what is going on.

And remember it is ok to block the user for couple of seconds and give them a flawless experience afterwards. instead of not blocking and give them slow experience (file IO).